# Hibernate lucene search collections and enums

Tags: hibernate, collections, enums, lucene, hibernate-search

i am trying to implement a search feature in my application using hibernate search(lucene). Simple searchs on String fields are working perfect, but now things come more complecated....
I hope you can give me some hints or samples.

I have the following Entities...

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class ChildClass {

    @Enumerated
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
    private EnumType enumType;
    ....

    //getter setter

}
```

========================================

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class ParentClass {

@IndexEmbeded
List<ChildClass> childs;

   //getter setter...

}
```

========================================

```
public enum EnumType {
  a,b,c
}
```

=======================================

Now i try to search and find for example:

*"find a List of ParentClasses which have childs where child.enumtype = a"*

I can do this with hql or native sql queries. but how to do it with hibernate lucene queries.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just for clarification

for Maps e.g

 @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.NO)
    @IndexedEmbedded(depth = 1)
    private Map<Integer, String> comments;
 
i can use a query like:

 luceneQuery = queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("comments").matching(
                    searchString).createQuery();
            booleanJunction.should(luceneQuery);
   
this qurey returns results as expected.
I have Problem with the use case described above

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `@IndexedEmbedded` does not apply to this case - it seems to me that your child class is an entity, as usual in child entities, they refer to their parent, so the parent class has a bidirectional mapping for their children.

As stated [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/3.2/reference/en/html/search-mapping.html#search-mapping-associated) (`Address` being the use case example)

> To make sure the Place Lucene document is updated when it's Address
>   changes, you need to mark the other side of the bidirectional
>   relationship with @ContainedIn.
>
> @ContainedIn is only useful on associations pointing to entities as
>   opposed to embedded (collection of) objects.

Perhaps you could try the `@ContainedIn` annotation on your `child` list.

In summary:

- you can use @IndexedEmbedded from `Child` to `Parent` (on parent property)
- you can use @ContainedIn from `Parent` to `Collection<Child>` (bi-directional)

Comment: Thanks for response, I understand so far, but how should the luceneQurery look like for the szenario above, as you can see i have already tried @IndexEmbedded